# Can I embed PowerPoint slides in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a Shiny app for a class that I am teaching.  Most of my content is markdown/RMarkdown but I want to embed some PowerPoint slides. I know I can show the MD documents with `includeMarkdown()`. Is there a similar way to embed Powerpoint Slides in a shiny app (and let the user click through them) without having to render the slides into another format?

Comment: OP, this is a good question, actually.  There's tons of info on creating powerpoint slides within a shiny app, but not the other way around (showing a powerpoint presentation).  I suppose you may have to convert the .ppt file to somethind that can be rendered.

Comment: Thank you. Given the number of educators who are used to powerpoint it seems like a good project to go after but I fear it is a **big** lift.